# How do i align button in table display without adding any divs

Tags: css, css-tables

http://jsfiddle.net/mXbfe/

Im trying to align the button with the input box without adding div tag. Can i do it just by CSS? i tried margin-top and padding-top on the input.submit but it doesnt work?

Here are the CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 50%; 
    display: table; /*padding: 1em 0 0; */
    background: green;
}

#inner {
     display: table-cell; 
     /*width: 100%;*/ 
    background: red;
}

input {
    width: 100%; 
    /*padding: .5em 1em;*/
}
```

Here are the HTML:

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner'>
        <label>Eat</label>
        <input type='textbox'></input>
    </div>
    <input class='button_submit' type='submit'></input>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are trying to vertically align things, 
give vertical-align: middle to label & input tags :
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/mXbfe/10/

Comment: The position of the label and text box is just the way i wanted. I just wanted the submit button to align at the right level with the input box? Can i do that without making the lable float left align with the textbox?

Comment: any problem in changing html structure.. ?

Comment: I could but im trying to find the ways with the current html structure? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have the input style with width=100%? To the text box and button to be the same size? To keep the word "Eat" above the input?

Comment: Updated. Eat label display as a block

Comment: you can make submit button absolute positioned to #outer. ( it is a bad approach, but works )
   http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/mXbfe/16/

Comment: Thanks aslan. Bad approach? What are the drawbacks of having done it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `input` in your css to `input[type=submit]`

Answer (score 0):

Move your `display: table` and `display: table-cell` declarations down a level: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mXbfe/5/)**

```
#inner {
    display: table;
}

input, label {
    display: table-cell;
}

.button_submit {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make align the divs using `display:table` property. In your code you haven't apply any stlye for input button field.

Here is a Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/mXbfe/24/

Have a look at this CSS.

```
#outer {
    width: 50%; 
    display: table; /*padding: 1em 0 0; */
    background: green;
}
#inner {
     display: table-cell; 
     /*width: 100%;*/ 
    background: red;
}
input[type="submit"]{display: table-cell;}
```